# How to get DataGrid.SelectedIndex from another ".cs" file?(MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Earlier when I wanted to edit a row in a DataGrid then I just set the cursor on the row of a DataGtid and wrote such code in a method of a codebehind form(xxx.xaml.cs):

```
int k = XXXDataGrid.SelectedIndex;
```

and then I could retrieve data from a row of a DataGrid.
  Now I try to use MVVM pattern of WPF and I have read that all my CRUD operations should pe written in Models. OKAY. I tried to take "DataGrid.SelectedIndex" but it is not possible without creating a handler in codebehind file.

I would like to know how can I take "DataGrid.SelectedIndex" and data of a row of a DataGrid from other classes situated in "Models" of MVVM.

When are value types stored in stack?
 I have read a lot of books of C# and always when I read about values and references types then to my mind comes a question: When are value types  stored in stack? Cause programmer cannot initializes any value type out from class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewModel will have Properties that are populated Model objects.  Here you will assign them so the View will be able to display data.

```
    public ParentModel 
    {
        get { return parentModel; }
        private set
        {
            if (parentModel != value)
            {
                parentModel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ParentModel");
            }
        }
    }


    public int SelectedItemIndex
    {
        get { return selectedItemIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedItemIndex != value)
            {
                selectedItemIndex = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItemIndex");
            }
        }
    }
```

The View will contain the object to display data, be it DataGrid, ComboBox etc. You can use ItemTemplates to customize how the data is displayed, but the key is to `bind` your data to the control.  This can allow data to flow in either the direction mode of only ViewModel to View (OneWay), or View to ViewModel (OneWayToSource), or both (TwoWay).  So as the user changes the selected index, the data will flow back to the ViewModel as it is set for TwoWay below.  The ItemsSource here is set as OneWay so only the ViewModel can change that for the View.

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParentModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedItemIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

If ViewModels need to interact with BusinessLogic, just pass the Data. If a seperate ViewModel needs the information, you'll need to use the concept available in your framework, eg. EventAggregator (Prism), to pass data around since they won't have knowledge of each other.

---

Core concept of MVVM is the binding of models and WPF controls' properties like this. I think you'll want to read up more on it to fully utilize the power and design.  Some very helpful questions/answers can be found on StackOverflow, MSDN has several good tutorials, etc.

Comment: Please, share with me links of good tutorials. I have found a lot of articles, however I cannot find tutorials with binding to Datagrid

Comment: @StepUp [This](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/11/07/in-the-box-ndash-mvvm-training/) is a very thorough startwhich you can follow and as you have questions you'll utilize SO/MSDN to learn more about particulars.